# Backbone collection initialize function test with mocha

Tags: backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

How would I write the test for the `options.url` parameter of the `initilaize` function of a `Backbone.Collection`?

I have the following code  and am having trouble writing the test for it. I am using `Mocha`, `Chai` and `Sinonjs`. When I comment-out `this.url = options.url` in my Backbone Collection the tests pass, but when I un-comment it I get the following assertion error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'options.url')`

My Backbone code:

```
Foo.Collection._entity = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '',        //API's endpoint for this collection
    fetched: false, //flag to avoid fetching twice if consecutive fetches occur

    /**
     * Makes sure the URL is set
     * @param {Object[]} models Set of initial models
     * @param {Object} options Regular initialization options object
     */
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        models = models || [];
        this.url = options.url;
    }
});
```

My tests for this Collection

```
describe("Foo.Collection._entity", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        // Sinon fake server for the backend
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

        // Server automatically responds to XHR requests

        this.server.autoRespond = true;

        this.entity = new Foo.Collection._entity();

    });

    afterEach(function () {
        // stop fake server
        this.server.restore();
    });

    describe("Default values", function () {

        // test default values
        it("has default values", function () {
            expect(this.entity).to.be.ok;
            expect(this.entity).to.have.length(0);
        });

        it("default url to be ' '",function() {
            var entity = this.entity;
            expect(entity.url).to.be.equal("");
        });

        it("fetched flag to be set to false", function (){
            var entity = this.entity;
            expect(entity.fetched).to.be.equal(false);
        });
    });
});
```

How would I write a test to pass the `this.url = options.url` snippet?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's as simple as just instantiating the Collection with the correct parameters in a `beforeEach` function, for example, and then testing the url and the length of the Collection.

```
 this.entity = new Foo.Collection._entity({options:
            {
                url: "/Foo"
            }
        });

   describe("Default values", function () {

        // test default values
        it("has default values", function () {
            expect(this.entity).to.be.ok;
            expect(this.entity).to.have.length(1);
            expect(entity.url).to.be.equal("Foo");
        });
```